# Is my ESP8266 faulty? Not turning on

Tags: arduino, serial, breadboard, esp8266

I got an ESP-12Q ESP8266 module and I am trying to upload Arduino firmware on it. But I can't even get any response from the module at all. No LEDs anywhere are on, I don't even know if the thing is dead or if my wiring is wrong. I get not even a single sign this thing is alive on the serial monitor. I have tried different baud rates. I don't know if it is a faulty unit because I can't tell if it is on. Absolutely nothing.

I have wired it up as follows:

[image]

I have also tried using 10k resistors to connect between the GPIOs and the VCC and ground but no luck. I also tried using the Arduino UNO to act as USB to Serial (tx-tx, rx-rx) but nothing.

I am about to toss this unit in the bin because I am completely at a loss right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have provided a _wiring diagram_ for your system. These are not liked on this site as they don't show the schema or circuit intent and attract a lot of down-votes. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. Add a _schematic_ and leave the other thing there for reference in case you have a wiring error. Also provide links to any devices referenced.

Comment: I have no idea how to create a schematic, it is beyond my knowledge as I am just a mere hobbyist. I had a look at the editor and had no idea how to even begin. Since this is a rather simple circuit, I hope it will suffice.

Comment: Some of the usb to serial devices cannot power an esp8266, it may be as simple as that.  I had the same problem with my first one.

Comment: I am powering the ESP externally using a 3.3v regulator as you can see in the diagram, I did notice a lot of people had that issue which is why I decided to go with external power from the get-go.

Comment: Do you have a way to measure the voltage being supplied to VCC of the ESP device? What part is used for the 3.3v regulator - are you sure it can supply 300mA of current? You likely need 10uF or more on the 3.3v line. Try adding a capacitor across 3.3-GND.

Comment: I haven't measured the voltage being supplied but im using a LD33CV regulator which says it can provide up to 800ma of current. I'll try add the capacitor and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that stood out for me was mentioning wiring from RX to RX and TX to TX. Typically you would wire RX(A) to TX(B) and TX(A) to RX(B) where A is the one device and B is the other device.

The pins are named from the perspective of each device. So device A's RX is where A expects to receive data and A's TX is where A expects to transmit data. Similarly, device B's RX is where B expects to receive data and B's TX is where B expects to transmit data.

Try changing the wiring of those pins and hopefully it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is indeed wired from RX(A) to TX(B) and TX(A) to RX(B). I have however also tried swapping those two to see if it would work but no luck.

Comment: Try connecting GPIO0 to GND and GPIO2 to 3.3V

Comment: I've tried that as well. As I understand it, GPIO0 should be pulled to ground only when flashing.

Answer (score 1):

- The chip in your wiring diagram is upside down, can you add a photo of your setup just to double check?
- pl-2303 works at 5v, ESP8266 works at 3.3v, there's a good chance you're lucky, but you could have already fried the module.
- Triple check your wiring, measure voltages, especially the 3.3v (under load!)
- You have no capacitors at all, I would put a/some 10/100uf caps before and after the power regulator, I think the spec says it needs at least a 10uf somewhere.
- Not sure if leds will blink on the ESP-12Q, haven't got one, but it might do nothing without firmware. It should print something at 74880 baud when powered on though, regardless of the firmware (or lack of).
- I would recommend using 10k's for pulling up/down the GPIO's, it will make it less likely to cause harm to the ESP, but it shouldn't influence the problem your having.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

1. Verify your voltage regulator is providing the appropriate voltage (test at the Gnd Vcc pins of the ESP).
2. Add a capacitor to the regulated supply to even out supply voltage.
3. Remove the UART from the circuit.
4. Post a photo of your actual circuit for comparison against your diagram.